# Programming Secant Method into Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

The sum of two numbers is 20. If each number is added to its square root, the product of the two sums is 155.55. Use Secant Method to approximate, to within 10^(-4), the value of the two numbers.

Comment: Goodluck with your homework.

Comment: I do not need or want the code to the entire problem. I would like help trying to program the secant method into Python. I figured out how to solve the problem using Newton's method, but I would like to compare it to the secant method. I know I will need two different initial guesses but I am unsure on how to create the for loop that will incorporate both of the guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://campus.murraystate.edu/academic/faculty/wlyle/420/Secant.htm

```
#inital guess
x1 = 10

x2 = 50
Epsilon = 1e-4
#given function
def func(x): 
    return abs(x)**0.5 * (abs(x)+20)**0.5 - 155.55

y1 = func(x1)
y2 = func(x2)

#loop max 20 times
for i in range(20):
    ans = x2 - y2 * (x2-x1)/(y2-y1)
    y3 = func(ans)
    print("Try:{}\tx1:{:0.3f}\tx2:{:0.3f}\ty3:{:0.3f}".format(i,x1, x2, y3))
    if (abs(y3) < Epsilon):
        break

    x1, x2 = x2, ans
    y1, y2 = y2, y3

print("\n\nThe numbers are: {:0.3f} and {:0.3f}".format(ans, ans+20))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Based on Your Title**

This code works well in most of the cases. Taken from [Secant Method Using Python (Output Included)](https://www.codesansar.com/numerical-methods/secant-method-python-program.htm)

```
# Defining Function
def f(x):
    return x**3 - 5*x - 9

# Implementing Secant Method

def secant(x0,x1,e,N):
    print('\n\n*** SECANT METHOD IMPLEMENTATION ***')
    step = 1
    condition = True
    while condition:
        if f(x0) == f(x1):
            print('Divide by zero error!')
            break

        x2 = x0 - (x1-x0)*f(x0)/( f(x1) - f(x0) ) 
        print('Iteration-%d, x2 = %0.6f and f(x2) = %0.6f' % (step, x2, f(x2)))
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x2
        step = step + 1

        if step > N:
            print('Not Convergent!')
            break

        condition = abs(f(x2)) > e
    print('\n Required root is: %0.8f' % x2)


# Input Section
x0 = input('Enter First Guess: ')
x1 = input('Enter Second Guess: ')
e = input('Tolerable Error: ')
N = input('Maximum Step: ')

# Converting x0 and e to float
x0 = float(x0)
x1 = float(x1)
e = float(e)

# Converting N to integer
N = int(N)


#Note: You can combine above three section like this
# x0 = float(input('Enter First Guess: '))
# x1 = float(input('Enter Second Guess: '))
# e = float(input('Tolerable Error: '))
# N = int(input('Maximum Step: '))

# Starting Secant Method
secant(x0,x1,e,N)
```